# ghc-mod expecting MonadBaseControl to have `StM` associated newtype instead of `StT` associated type

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, type-families, ghc-mod

I'm getting this error from installing the latest ghc-mod (5.2.1.1) from Hackage in a sandbox:

```
[15 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.CabalConfig ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/CabalConfig.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-94286619/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/CabalConfig.o )
[16 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.CabalApi ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/CabalApi.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-94286619/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/CabalApi.o )
[17 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Cradle ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cradle.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-94286619/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Cradle.o )
[18 of 38] Compiling Language.Haskell.GhcMod.Monad ( Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Monad.hs, dist/dist-sandbox-94286619/build/Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Monad.o )

Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Monad.hs:370:5:
    Wrong category of family instance; declaration was for a type synonym
    In the newtype instance declaration for ‘StM’
    In the instance declaration for ‘MonadBaseControl IO (GhcModT m)’
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghc-mod-5.2.1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I've never seen this error before, so I went digging. In `Language/Haskell/GhcMod/Monad.hs`, sure enough it's doing something funny:

```
instance (MonadBaseControl IO m) => MonadBaseControl IO (GhcModT m) where
    newtype StM (GhcModT m) a = StGhcMod {
          unStGhcMod :: StM (StateT GhcModState
                              (ErrorT GhcModError
                                (JournalT GhcModLog
                                  (ReaderT GhcModEnv m) ) ) ) a } 
    liftBaseWith f = GhcModT . liftBaseWith $ \runInBase ->
        f $ liftM StGhcMod . runInBase . unGhcModT
```

If you look [at monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html) on Hackage, there *is no such* `StM` associated newtype, but only an `StT` associated type.

Unless there's some other type trickery going on here, I'm stumped. How would this be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scratch this, my eyes are fooling me. My mistake, since monad-control-1.x, MonadControl has had an associated type instead of an associated data type, as explained [here](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod/issues/421).

Comment: Is there a way to fix or work around this? I'm just getting started with Haskell and can't install ghc-mod because of this. What can I do?

Comment: Ah. Figured it out. I ran `cabal install ghc-mod --constraint='monad-control < 1.0.0.0'` and it worked.